Powershell variable found in expression is not defined
I have a small script that (debatably) creates a list of AD users that have never logged in. It uses a variable $groupPattern to limit the search to only groups that I'm interested in.
When I use the variable with Get-ADGroup it returns an error:
Get-ADGroup: Variable: 'groupPattern' found in expression: $groupPattern is not defined.

If I enclose the variable in quotes it runs, but returns zero results. If I skip the variable and use the pattern directly in the query it runs properly.
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$OutFile
)

$totalInactive = 0
$groupPattern = "Specific-Group-*"
# $adGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter { ( Name -like $groupPattern ) } # Throws error
# $adGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter { ( Name -like "$groupPattern" ) } # Runs but returns 0 results
$adGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter { ( Name -like "Specific-Group-*" ) } # Runs successfully

"Users in each group who have never logged into their DOSDEV accounts" | Out-File $OutFile

foreach ($group in $adGroups.Name) {
    $count = 0
    
    "$group`n-----------------" | Out-File $OutFile -Append
    $groupMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | Where-Object { ($_.objectClass -eq "user" ) -and ($_.distinguishedName -notlike "*Disabled Accounts*") }

    foreach ($member in $groupMembers) {
        $account = Get-ADUser -Identity $member.SamAccountName -Properties *

        if (-not $account.lastLogonTimestamp) {
            $samAcctName = $account.SamAccountName
            $email = $account.EmailAddress
            "  $samAcctName    $email" | Out-File $OutFile -Append
            $count++
        }
        
    }
    
    "-----------------`n  $count`n" | Out-File $OutFile -Append
    $totalInactive += $count
}
"  Total: $totalInactive" | Out-File $OutFile -Append

Why does using the variable cause problems? Does it have to do with scoping and the -Filter block
Also, feel free to offer suggestions for how I can improve this overall.

Even tho it can work in some cases, passing a scriptblock to the -Filter parameter of AD Cmdlets is not supported. You should always use a string. Change -Filter { ( Name -like $groupPattern ) } to -Filter "Name -like '$groupPattern'".

While conceptually problematic, -Filter { ( Name -like $groupPattern ) } would normally work (even though it's better expressed as -Filter 'Name -like $groupPattern'). It wouldn't work if your Get-ADGroup command uses implicit remoting, however, in which case string interpolation via "...." is a must. See the second linked duplicate for details and further constraints.

@mklement0 Read your answer in the second duplicate. Very informative. Thanks!

Glad to hear it, @theillien; thanks for the nice feedback.
